# Send Text value from 2 Labels using Command inside BindableLayout

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, icommand, bindable

I'm working with MVVM and I have a bindablelayout like this:

```
 <StackLayout Margin="20" BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding MyApartments}" >
      <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>

           <StackLayout Margin="0,10,0,0">
              <Frame Padding="15" HasShadow="True" BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HeightRequest="150" CornerRadius="15">
                  <StackLayout x:Name="AptItems">
                    <Label x:Name="apartmentlabel" Text="{Binding MyApartments.apartment}" Margin="0,15,0,0" FontFamily="{StaticResource mon_extrabold}" TextColor="DarkBlue" FontSize="Title"/>
                    <Label x:Name="numberlabel" Text="{Binding MyApartments.number}" FontFamily="{StaticResource mon_bold}" TextColor="DarkBlue" FontSize="Subtitle"/>
                    <Button HorizontalOptions="End" FontFamily="{StaticResource mon_regular}" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource bounty}" TextColor="White" Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.SelectApartment, Source={x:Reference ApartmentsPage}}"/>
                  </StackLayout>
             </Frame>
         </StackLayout>

       </DataTemplate>
     </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
   </StackLayout>
```

I need to save the value in buildinglabel and numberlabel to my preferences but I don't know how to pass both labels to a command and searched for a long time now with no success, how is it done?

Comment: you don't pass the labels, you pass the object that the labels are bound to.  Since both labels get their values from properties on MyApartments, just pass MyApartments as the CommandParameter

Comment: @Jason yes I read about that but I don't get it how do I write the parameter? :(
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/43904/how-to-pass-multiple-parameters-using-command-interface

Comment: `CommandParameter="{Binding MyApartments}"`

Comment: @Jason I can't say I didn't tried that but then my problem has to be the command :( what's wrong with it?

public CustomerApartmentsViewModel()
        {
            SelectApartment = new Command<object>((x) => openPost(x), (x) => InternetActive);            
        }
        public void openPost(object x)
        {
            var ButtonApartment = x as Apartment;
            AptId = ButtonApartment.apartment;
            NumberId = ButtonApartment.number;            
        }

Comment: before we even get to that, I suspect the binding on your Labels is incorrect.  Is `Text="{Binding MyApartments.apartment}"` actually displaying what you want it to in the label?  It seems like it would display the same values on every row.

Comment: @json yes it was didn't noticed that just part of the intents I made to make it work but it's corrected and it does display all the elements I need but I just can't make the button work no how no why and I need to deliver this today I'm frustrated by now sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199489/discussion-between-jason-and-herb).